# Trying to read a file till the very end(not working)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read a file(a ROM actually). The thing is that my program stops before actually reaching the end of the file. Here's what I wrote:

```
int main(){
cout << "Entter the file to read in HEX: " ;
string fileName;
cin >> fileName;

ifstream streamLecture(fileName);
unsigned char charLu;
while(!streamLecture.eof()){
    streamLecture >> charLu;        
    cout<< hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << short(charLu) << ' ';
}
streamLecture.close();

cout << endl;
}
```

This program cout a few lines of HEX values but I know there are a lot more since I  read the file in a HEX editor program.

EDIT: Ok, so i'm assuming there is an EOF in the middle of my file, how do I skip it or continue reading afterwards? Thanks again

Comment: Try using `while (streamLecture.get(charLu)) { //...` instead of `>>`.

Comment: @ZacHowland The problem is not the loop but why it's stopping before the end. I've tried with 
while(streamLecture >> charLu)
but it's still stopping and I have no idea why. Thanks

Comment: @jxh Same problem as before, stops reading before the end

Comment: @user2888798 The only way your loop will break is after the `eof` bit is set, which won't happen until after you have read the actual EOF.  That is, it will read more than it should, not less ... unless you have an EOF in the middle of your file.

Comment: @ZacHowland Ok, so i'm assuming there is an EOF in the middle of my file, how do I skip it or continue reading afterwards?

Comment: @user2888798 You don't (well, shouldn't).  That is a malformed file.  That likely isn't your problem (unless you are trying to read in a binary file while still in text mode) - what is the data in your file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your file in binary mode, and use `get()`:

```
    ifstream streamLecture(fileName, std::ios::binary);
    while (streamLecture.get(charLu)) {
        cout<< hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << short(charLu) << ' ';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
while(streamLecture >> charLu){
    cout<< hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << short(charLu) << ' ';
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Well it reads fine for a few lines but it stops. I'm guessing it's hitting some kind of eof (end  of file character) and stopping before the end. Any ideas?